# Problems accessing my servers - but only from German providers

Tags: cdn, networking, accessibility

I'm having a problem that I've been trying to resolve for months to no avail.

I have several websites hosted on a dedicated server in the US. Those include 
http://noduslabs.com 
http://waytorussia.net
http://polysingularity.com

I have a major problem accessing those sites from my providers in Germany. In fact, I'm using two different ones, Alice (Telefonica / O2) and Deutsche Telekom – the IPs are:
62.158.89.238
78.52.163.124

and from both of them it takes really long to reach the websites. Sometimes I cannot do it at all.

However, when I switch to a Proxy that goes through UK, everything's fine.

We did traceroute and everything, my hosting provider says that the problem is between my German providers and the providers in the US, but nobody seems to be able to solve it.

Can you recommend something I can do about it?

Should I just move my sites to another provider with a better CDN?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It takes too long for your server to send its first bits of data. So you are having either a major connectivity problem (unlikely imo) or your pages are just taking to long to create on the backend (wordpress). It takes almost 10 seconds for noduslabs and polysingularity to load from my US location. the other site seems reasonable.

Review your backend code / plugins etc. tracert is generally a useless tool when actually diagnosing something with so many moving parts.

I assume you see the speed differences with the EU proxy, because said proxy is doing caching.

Comment: Thank you! It's strange because it's just standard WP sites... do you think it makes sense to copy them on another server and do the comparison like this?